# Qual é a diferença entre as propriedades de configurações <compilation> e <httpRuntime>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web.config

Estou passando por algumas problemas enquanto aprendo a trabalhar com C#, mais especificamente com Asp Net MVC.

Eu vi um trecho de configuração no `Web.config` que me deixou um pouco confuso, a saber:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Como é possível perceber, parece que cada um tem configurações de `targetFramework` diferentes.

Eu gostaria de saber:

- Qual é a diferença entre `compilation` e `httpRuntime`?
- O que cada uma dessas configurações afeta, no caso da opção `targetFramework`?

Answer (score 1):

Como já [respondido por @Tetsuya Yamamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40170567/what-do-the-targetframework-settings-mean-in-web-config-in-asp-net-mvc) em outra pergunta, resumidamente é isso:

O `compilation` seleciona qual versão dos assemblies de referência do .NET Framework é usada ao executar a compilação.

E o `httpRuntime` para dizer que o projeto atual foi projetado para usar assemblies de tempo de execução do .NET 4.5 sem recompilar assemblies de projeto existentes na máquina de implementação antes de carregá-lo na memória.

O `targetFramework` no `web.config` serve para manter os problemas de compatibilidade entre as alterações de cada versão do .NET Framework. E a diferença entre `targetFramework` na `compilation` e `httpRuntime` pertence a cada ambiente de desenvolvimento e implementação.